# Best way to manage weapons as GameObject on a script in Unity with C#

Tags: c#, 2d, unity

I have a player game-object with a script Player. In the Player script I have a public properties weapons.

I want to have to just drag in this properties a script/prefabs. And the Player script must can get the properties of the weapons selected.

**For example:** imagine, we have two weapons, one is a **pistol** with **5 attack power**, the other is a **knife** with **7 attack power**.

Now I want to set pistol in the Player script.
[image]

What should I drag here ? A game-object with a weapon script ? Or a weapons script who instantiate a weapon ? Or maybe an another solution ...

The idea is to be able to create easily some weapons without scripting more. Just place a sprite, and modify some properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always just stuff all weapons in one big list and access them with an index.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Weapon
{
    public string name;
    public float damage;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Player
{
    public Weapon[] weapons;
    public int currentWeapon;
}

public Player player;
```

[image]